# How to do design list view like SharePoint 2010 Custom List or Document Library?

Tags: user-interface, list, sharepoint-2010

I am generation Recent Activity list from SharePoint 2010 site,
What i need is ,i have to display the list in a particular page,The UI must be like a SharePoint 2010 Custom List or Document Library,

How to design it, Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Are you displaying this on a page in SharePoint? If so does the page live in the same site as your Recent Activity list? How is your Recent Activity list generated??

Comment: i have created the new web part to display the recent activity in that i have used Grid View to bind the data

Answer (score 1):

If your data source is a SharePoint list, you could use the [ListViewWebPart][1] to achieve this. What exactly are the requirements of the view - should you also include the context-sensitive menu ("Edit properties" etc) ? If not, you could just create a custom web part and override the `CreateChildControls` method, and there mimic the html/css that is rendered in a document library.